# Force trailing slash before an anchor tag

Tags: .htaccess, tags, anchor

I'm looking for a way to force adding a trailing slash before an anchor tag whenever  there is an anchor tag without a trailing slash . Could it be achieved with htaccess?

Example :

localhost/pp/pages#edit/12

localhost/pp/pages/manage#edit/file/12

--->
 localhost/pp/pages/#edit/12

localhost/pp/pages/manage/#edit/file/12

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's abit cheaky but use you favorite Javascript lib or go raw todo something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get all internal anchor tags that dont have trailing slash
    $('a[href^="/"]').not('[href$="/"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', function(i, link) {
            return link +'/';
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Sure! but i want it to be done even if i type it in the browser.

Comment: Both will work? I assume this is just for vanity when navigating around your site